# Find point along line where normal extends through another point

Tags: geometry, line, point, normals

Given the line segment AB, how do I find the point P<sub>n</sub> where the normal to AB passes through the point P? I also need to know if there is no normal that passes through the point (e.g. the point Q).

[image: Line's normal through point]

Comment: You have 2 answers, care to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `R` is *any* point on the normal line passing through `P` (different from `P`), then `Pn` is the point where `AB` and `PR` intersect.

One way to generate point `R` is to rotate segment `AB` by 90 degrees and then translate it so that `A` coincides with `P`. The the translated `B` is your `R`:

```
Rx = Px + (By - Ay)
Ry = Py - (Bx - Ax)
```

Once you have your point `R`, it becomes a simple [line-line intersection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection), which will give you your `Pn` (the formulas can be simplified for a specific case of perpendicular lines).

Then you can easily check whether `Pn` lies between `A` and `B` or not.

**P.S.** Note that solution provided in @MBo's answer is a more direct and efficient one (and if you combine and simplify/optimize the formulas required for my answer you will eventually arrive at the same thing). What I describe above might make good sense if you *already have* a primitive function that calculates the intersection of two lines, say,

```
find_intersection(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy, Dx, Dy)
// Intersect AB and CD
```

In that case finding `Pn` becomes a simple one-liner

```
Pn = find_intersection(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Px, Py, Px + (By - Ay), Py - (Bx - Ax))
```

But if you don't have such primitive function at your disposal and/or care for making your code more efficient, then you might want to opt for a more direct dedicated sequence of calculations like the one in @MBo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Find vectors

```
AB = (B.X-A.X, B.Y-A.Y)
AP = (P.X-A.X, P.Y-A.Y)
```

Projection of **P** to **AB** is:

```
APn = AB * (AB.dot.AP) / (AB.dot.AB);
```

where .dot. is scalar product

In coordinates:

```
cf = ((B.X-A.X)*(P.X-A.X)+(B.Y-A.Y)*(P.Y-A.Y))/((B.X-A.X)^2+(B.Y-A.Y)^2)

if cf < 0 or cf > 1 then projection lies outside AB segment

Pn.X = A.X + (B.X-A.X) * cf
Pn.Y = A.Y + (B.Y-A.Y) * cf
```